# How to upgrade from 12.04.1 LTS to 12.04.4 LTS from USB?

Tags: 12.04

I want to upgrade from 12.04.1 LTS to 12.04.4 LTS and there is no GUI. Which is the best way to upgrade to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need USB for that because it is not upgrade it is **Update** !

Open a `tty` Terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Note:

- the first command updates packages list
- the second command downloads and updates software installed on your PC

Comment: My question was edited. I had put the update image is on a usb and that is what I want to use.

Comment: would still like to know how to upgrade/update from usb, but I have a query about the two apt-get commands. someone has suggested I use the following:

Comment: do-release-upgrade and apt-get upgrade - what is the difference?